# Bind EditorTemplate file to grid combobox in Kendo UI MVC

Tags: telerik-grid, telerik-mvc, kendo-ui

Imagine I have the grid on the file on **/Views/Home/Index.cshtml**:

```
 @model IEnumerable<KendoMVCWrappers.Models.StockWebAndDetailsView>

@( Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)

               .Name("Grid")
                @* Other columns and dataSource in here *@
                columns.Bound("QuantityToEnquiry").Filterable(false).Sortable(false)
                     .EditorTemplateName("QuantityToEnquiry"); 

               })
```

And I have the file on **/Views/EditorTemplateName/QuantityToEnquiry.cshtml** ( I also tried on  **~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/**):

```
 @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
        .Name("QuantityToEnquiry")
        .Value("1")
            .BindTo(Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList())
```

On the model I have:

```
public class StockWebAndDetailsView
{
    [UIHint("QuantityToEnquiry")]
            public int QuantityToEnquiry { get; set; }
}
```

The data that is showing is **null**, a string with value "null", I don't know why.

Comment: What do you mean by "The data that is showing is null"? Is it in the dropdown list? What happens when you use Html.DropDownList?

Comment: Hi @AtanasKorchev it outputs a null string, instead of a combobox.

Comment: And what does Html.DropDownList output in this case?

Comment: Same output, seems that is not finding the file

Comment: And is your property decorated with the UIHint attribute? ASP.NET MVC won't find it unless you specify with the UIHint what the editor template is called.

Comment: Hi @AtanasKorchev, I populated the field like on the edited question now, and still is rerturning "null".

Comment: Editor templates should be put in ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/. This is a basic requirement. Find more info about editor templates here: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html

Comment: Hi @AtanasKorchev, also tried it, still null :(

Comment: Sorry can't help further. You need to get editor templates working first.

Answer (score 1):

Yo mate,

First I suggest you to put that editor template under the Shared/EditorTemplates folder. And then I suggest you to name the combobox with the same name as your property.

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
    .Name("QuantityToEnquiry")
    .Value("1")
        .BindTo(Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList())
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @XMR , but didn't work still. :(
I am still getting null from Quantity To Enquiry